# Giving access to domain-joined VM using Azure Lighthouse

Tags: azure, rdp, lighthouse

Let's assume that we have two tenants: A & B. Some groups from tenant A have access to resources in tenant B via Azure Lighthouse. Is there any possibility to give access and the possibility to log into domain-joined virtual machines via RDP stored in tenant B using that setup for users who have access to tenant B via Azure Lighthouse?